# how do I set ANSI_NULLS ON or OFF for a query in ADO.NET?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net

say i want to set the `ansi_nulls` on/or off for an individual sql server query in ADO.NET. how do I do it?

Comment: Could you provide some source code for context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `SET ANSI_NULLS ON` or `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`

Important: [this will always be ON in future](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx)

> In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will always be ON and any applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use this feature.

Personally, setting this OFF to allow `= NULL` to work is dangerous, foolish and non-standard

Comment: Did you mean>>Run SET ANSI_NULLS ON or SET ANSI_NULLS OFF?

Comment: @Pavel Nefyodov: yes, I did. Thank you